# Laravel SAML (laravel-saml2) - Config Issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, wampserver, saml

I'm trying to get SSO working on an application, first time doing anything with this type of thing and falling at first hurdle.

Having some basic issues getting started here. Not totally sure where I am going wrong.

Trying to use https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2; Running Laravel 5.4 on a development WAMPserver; installed the package fine, added provider and alias information to `config/app.php` as per all instructions.

If I try to publish the config file, I get no action, no error, just "Publishing Complete" in Composer.

I can copy the `saml2_settings.php` file to the config directory from the provider directory, and set the parameters there instead, however, no routes work - trying to get the metadata via `/saml2/metadata` URL just gives me a 404.

Any ideas - new to SAML but this seems just like a standard installation issue.

Comment: Did you startup your laravel server e.g with `php artisan serve` I am using Laravel 5.4 and this library works perfectly. I'll try a fresh L5.4 installation and get back to you if something has changed.

Comment: I just followed the instruction using Laravel 5.4 and I was able to retrieve the metadata at `myapp/saml2/metadata` without changing anything on the `config/saml2_settings.php`. You should check again if you're not doing anything wrong

Comment: After going through everything, seems that I just needed to run composer dump-autoload, as things had not registered correctly. Stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to add SAML2_IDP_HOST in env 
2) Your url must contan prefix 'routesPrefix' => '/saml2', so your routes looks like below,

```
 /**
     * If 'useRoutes' is set to true, the package defines five new routes:
     *
     *    Method | URI                      | Name
     *    -------|--------------------------|------------------
     *    POST   | {routesPrefix}/acs       | saml_acs
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/login     | saml_login
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/logout    | saml_logout
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/metadata  | saml_metadata
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/sls       | saml_sls
     */
```

Comment: I have the routes prefix set

'useRoutes' => true,
'routesPrefix' => '/saml2',

and URL I am using is localhost/public/saml2/metadata

Do I need to use anything other than the pre-set example SAML2_IDP_HOST in the saml2_settings.php file just to access the Metadata route - seems to me something not working with the actual routes to start with.

Comment: Do you define in route as well?